# dart, unit testing private methods

Tags: unit-testing, dart

I have a library which is quite large but only exposes a very tiny API to make it easy to use and learn for new users. I would like to keep my library this way, but I also want to ensure that I have as much unit test coverage as possible, I would like to be able to directly unit test all of my classes but so far as I can tell I can only unit test the public API of the library.

I can, of course, write unit tests to fully test the public methods which will effectively indirectly test all of the underlying private classes, but if a test fails it could mean a lot of digging around in the private code to find out where something went wrong, rather than having unit tests for each individual private class so when something goes wrong it's immediately apparent what went wrong and where.

Is there a design pattern to help with this situation or a way for unit testing to be written for private dart classes and methods?

Comment: I was thinking about exposing all private members by extending from each one a public Test class which adds nothing to the underlying private class, this way I can directly test through the exposed test classes and just tell users to ignore anythign that starts with "Test", but this seems very dirty

Comment: Can you split up your library in multiple libraries? If you move your private classes into a separate library in the same application then you can make them public and test them. You would then import them in your current library and not export them (so the user of your library still can't use your other classes as long as he doesn't import that other library himself).

Comment: so simple its genius!

Comment: Oh, if it's genius, I'll turn it into an answer :)

Comment: I answered this on another answer before realizing these are probably dupes, but see also `@visibleForTesting` here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21657315/how-to-test-a-private-function-in-dart?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you move your private classes into a separate library in the same application then you can make them public and test them. You would then import that library in your current library and not export it (so the user of your library still can't use your other classes as long as he doesn't import that other library himself).